# Cocoa error 3840 The operation couldn’t be completed

Tags: php, ios, json, cocoa, swift

I am trying to connect to my localhost API (that I need to build along with the iOS swift app) that returns a json string. The API is written in Laravel 4 framework.

Here is the iOS Swift code to connect and receive the code:

```
func checkEmail() {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3306/laravel/rojectapi/checkEmail"))
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var params = ["email":"myemail@me.com", "password":"password"] as Dictionary

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Body: \(strData)")
        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as NSDictionary

        println("hey")

        if(err) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            var success = json["success"] as? Int
            println("Success: \(success)")
        }
        })

    task.resume()

}
```

The Laravel PHP Route:

```
Route::post('/checkEmail', array(
'as' => 'checkEmail',
'uses' => 'FrontEndController@checkEmail'
));
```

And then the front-end-controller with the checkEmail method:

```
public function checkEmail() {

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|email'
    ));

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return $validator->messages()->toJson();
    } else {
        return Response::json(array('success' => true));
    }

}
```

Am I not connecting to the server correctly? I need to do so on my iPhone 5s connected to my laptop, as well as in the emulator. I have tried `name.local`, `localhost:<post>` and `name.local:<post>` in the URL.

**Update**

I got the code from [this tutorial](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/making-a-post-request-in-swift/)

Comment: Post the contents of `strData` as logged in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Either pass `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` (`.AllowFragments` in Swift) or format your JSON properly.

A simple google search revealed that error 3840 is caused due to improperly formatted JSON being passed to the iOS JSON parser.

Comment: Yes, I googled that too before posting. But have no idea how to fix it as I am pretty much new to development. How can I pass `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments to the JSON?

Comment: @josh Just as you passed `.MutableLeaves`.

Comment: I passed `.AllowFragments` to it separately, instead of, and with `.MutableLeaves` but they don't work. I still get the same error

Comment: @josh Then you have improper JSON. Post the contents of `strData` in your question.

Comment: I have opened charles proxy server (monitoring proxy calls) and it shows that the response is `J
5.5.380.JiTE?J8ˇ˜ÄvnCDhb4{/u%Tmysql_native_password!ˇÑ#08S01Got packets out of order`, which would explain why it is not reading as JSON. Because it is not JSON. How can I fix this though?

Comment: @josh No idea about that. Ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs if the API is expecting some data from you and you are not able to send it or it is not being received by the APi, try to Echo out the parameter which are received by the API as a response to your iOS Request, It may also occur if you APi Implementation has some error in it, though you may be able to see this error in your Web Console.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error, when i add languages to Localizations in project. When i add language, must change from "localizable strings" to "interface builder storyboard". I mean project of iOS app. Could help you.